# Why to use @Body annotation when a class object can be passed in method's argument?

Tags: android, annotations, retrofit2

in the method getLocation(), what difference will it make if i simply pass a TableParameter object?

```
    public interface MasterAPI {
    @POST("Master/getLocation")
    public Call<List<LocationGetTab>> getLocation(@Body TableParameter 
    parameter);
    }
```

Class TableParameter is so defined:

```
    public class TableParameter {
    @SerializedName("State")
    int State;
    @SerializedName("district")
    int District;
    @SerializedName("LocType")
    String locType;

    public TableParameter(int district, int state, String locType) {
    District = district;
    State = state;
    this.locType = locType;
    }
    }
```

Comment: read http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Body annotation is used when you are passing your object as a argument and those all parameter which are defined into model class those all data passes to your service as an individual argument as a request parameter.

Please read whole Retrofit Document it helps a lot to you.

Hope you understand.